# How to check if the memory is actually used by the OS in an Embedded Linux system?

Tags: memory, embedded, virtual-memory, yocto

This question needs additional clarifications.

Background: I am working on an embedded system (Xilinx zynq ultrascale+) which consists of an ARM processor + FPGA. The memory map (if I were to use the system as bare metal) is the following:

Attached to the ARM (as per datasheet):

```
Segment name | Start addresss     | Size
HP0_DDR_HIGH | 0x0_0008_0000_0000 | 32G 
HP0_DDR_LOW  | 0x0_0000_0000_0000 | 2G  
HP0_LPS_OCM  | 0x0_0000_FF00_0000 | 16M 
HP0_QSPI     | 0x0_0000_C000_0000 | 512M
```

Then I have some external RAM (4GB) that I access through a DDR controller in the FPGA. This memory lies here

```
Segment name          | Start addresss     | Size
C0_DDR4_ADDRESS_BLOCK | 0x0_0005_0000_0000 | 4G
```

When I build Linux I use the Xilinx Petalinux toolchain, which is Yocto in disguise. Once the system is live I can access the `0x5_0000_0000`external DDR using this physical address, through the `devmem` command, or by mmapping from user space the physical address.

I think that linux discovers this additional DDR through parsing the device tree at boot time.

One more detail: Looking at the datasheet (https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug1085-zynq-ultrascale-trm.pdf)

[image: ARM -> External DDR path]

It seems that the address doesn't go into any MMU translation unit.

Question(s):

1. How can I check if linux uses the external ddr as part of its possible pool of memory? I know that the OS keeps track of all the pages in memory, will this memory be paged?
2. Is the OS able to use this memory for creating and managing processes address space?
3. Assuming that I map this physical addresses to a user virtual address space in a process, does the kernel create new page entries?

Comment: This seems like more of a hardware question than linux - but the easiest way to check is to run `free` and see if the total ram roughly matches the RAM available to the ARM system plus the RAM available to the FPGA (it won't be an exact match because the kernel will reserve some for its own use).    Is the additional FPGA RAM supposed to be available for the host linux machine to use? or is it just for the FPGA?  what does `dmesg` or the kernel logs say about the extra RAM?

Comment: I will now run the tests you are suggesting, however in the meantime, what stack exchange community do you think would be better to post this question?

Comment: ". Is the additional FPGA RAM supposed to be available for the host linux machine to use?" this is what I would like to know. There is a gazillion options when configuring the kernel that I am surely missing something. Where should I check for this? As things are now, to me it does not make any difference if the memory is available to the host linux or not.

Comment: I would check the documentation and specifications of the hardware, for both the SBC you're using and the add-on FPGA.  If the hardware does not make the RAM available to the kernel as directly addressable RAM (instead of, e.g., simply providing a mechanism to upload and download data for the FPGA to use), there's no way that the kernel can use it as system ram.

Comment: The ram is addressable, I have written it in the question.